# Is Plaid's development environment more prone to need frequent reauthentication?

Tags: plaid

I'm using Python and Plaid's development environment to download bank balances and transactions. To get the initial access tokens, I'm launching Link from quickstart, and can do that in standard and update mode.

The problem I'm running into is how frequently my API call returns the ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED error and I have to re-authenticate. For a Regions account I've been testing, this happens a few times throughout the day. For a Pinnacle Financial Partners bank, this happens almost immediately after updating the access token. As in, I can log in through link, successfully fire an auth/get request, and by the time I can send another request (e.g., balance/get), I'm already getting ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED again.

As I'm evaluating Plaid for production use, is this frequent authentication atypical? Is it a known limitation with development, or with specific banks even on production? I've seen some banks (Bank of America) *only* work in production, but I'm hoping what I'm experiencing is just the nature of working in development. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Development vs. Production environments are virtually identical and shouldn't impact how often you hit `ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED`.

What you're seeing is atypical, though. Unless you have multi-factor auth turned on and configured not to trust known devices, this shouldn't happen.

Assuming you don't have that configured, would you mind submitting a support ticket so Plaid Support can look into this and help figure out why it's happening?

Comment: Thanks. I've contacted support and will post back here with anything helpful that comes of it.

Comment: @SteelReyn did you find anything out? i seem to also be having this issue